# Silverlight 3 (C#) vs. Flash 10 (AS3)

Tags: c#, silverlight, flash, actionscript-3

How does Silverlight stack up against Flash 10?

1. which is lighter? (CPU consumption, loading times, performance)
2. which has richer capabilities (APIs, libraries)
3. faster for developing?
4. what about media handling (audio/video streaming) ?
5. do I need special server/client software to use them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. which is lighter ? ( CPU consumption , loading times , speed of executing things etc .. )

   - They are comparable. [Bubblemark](http://bubblemark.com/) has a comparison that tries to benchmark them but I would take it with a grain of salt. Fact is, you can get decent performance with either. If you start staring too hard at micro-benchmarks you're gonna lose the point of using such high-level frameworks.
2. which has richer capabilities ( API-s , libraries etc.. )

   - This will depend on what it is you are trying to do. Silverlight has the .Net libs (not sure of the exact subset) which is probably nice. But ActionScript and Flash have been around for ages and have a huge community complete with almost any library you want. I think you would be hard pressed to find something one can do that the other cannot. I like ActionScript alright but I think I'd prefer C# as a development language.
3. faster for developing ?

   - Hate to keep saying "it depends" but that is the truth. If you know .Net and C# already you may be familiar with the Microsoft toolkit. Flash 10 can be programmed using Flash CS4 or Flex Builder (which is an IDE) so it depends if you are coming from an engineering or graphical design perspective on which you would use. I think MS would win the development tools battle but Adobe would win the integration with graphics tools battle. I don't mind Flex Builder and it hasn't let me down, but when I was developing using VS (C++) I was really pleased with the experience.
4. what about media handling ( audio/video streaming ) ?

   - youtube is Flash. Same with almost any other mainstream Audio/Video streaming site on the web (with few exceptions). That said, some of the new Silverlight demos show incredible video capability and control.
5. do i need special server/client software to use them ?

   - To deliver content through the browser, both require a plug-in. Flash is by far more ubiquitous at the moment. If you are going for sheer number of current installs then Flash is the best choice. Adobe also has Air which allows you to publish Flash content as a cross-platform desktop application. This does require the user has the Air runtime installed on their computer, but it would allow you to then create apps that run on Windows, OS X and Linux.

One thing I touched on which is really important is community size. The Flash community is much older and much larger. This is important because it is easier to find people who have done things similar to what you are trying to do. The number of tutorials, example code, blogs, forums, open-source 3rd party libraries, etc. makes it easy to learn ActionScript.

For me the decision comes down to a few questions for yourself:

1. Do you already know C#/.Net and Microsoft development tool-chains?
2. How important is the size of the current installed user base to your decision?
3. Are you interested in developing cross-platform desktop style applications as well as browser plug-in content?
4. Would you rather be a pioneer in a young platform or take the benefits of experience available in an older platform?

Comment: Talking about Bubblemark there is an outdated SL2 implementation. With optimized implementation SL3 bubblemark is 3 to 6 times faster mainly because it uses GPU hardware acceleration.
Also Silverlight is really faster (2-4 times) on computation intensive clauses.

Comment: Hello, First i want to thank you for the great answer ! Here is my answer to your question : 
1) I am already .net/C# developer
2) The community size is important alright , but if the app i have build wouldn't the user just make the effort to install the few megs plugin ? it wouldnt hurt him anyway, Right ? 
4) i think i wan to pioneer :)

Comment: Re: installation - some will install, some won't and some *can't* (e.g. corporate policy). That may or may not be an issue for the type of audience you are targeting. However, in a balanced look at the technologies it is essential to asses it as a risk.

Comment: Good answer.  I'd add to your #5 that Silverlight 3 supports an out-of-browser install, much like Air does for Flash, but without needing a separate add-on.

Comment: One way Silverlight responds to adobe Air is that it is so easy to migrate an application from Silverlight to a WPF desktop application, since they are both C#/XAML, use the same designers, and have similar (though not identical) object models.  Of course, WPF is not cross-platform.  However, Air is based on a interpreter whereas WPF is compiled/JITed, so WPF applications should be more performant.

Comment: Moonlight can work is quite a lot cases. And it supported out of browser before Microsoft did.

Answer (score 4):

3.By most accounts I've heard, C#/XAML is a more developer-friendly environment than actionscript.  It had better be - it was built years later.
4.Silverlight has [adaptive bitrate video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd159743.aspx).  I believe for Flash you need the Autobahn Flash extension to get that.  That's just one feature though, other people undoubtedly know of others where one wins over the other.

Comment: Having used Action Script for about 3 weeks in Flex Builder, after having been a C# developer for 4 years, I would say C# has many more features.  This doesn't necessarily make it "better" of course, that is subjective.  Microsoft's XAML and Adobe's MXML seem very similar in concept.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! this adaptive bitrate video is huge + for silverlight !

Comment: 3. MXML is older (2004) and more powerful, since it contains AS3 as a true subset (compare MXML and XAML data bindings or event handling). 4. the point here is the server and not the client. flash also can play back adaptive bitrate videos. it's just that the only server capable of doing that is some deluxe FMS version, which is quite costy. but i think the scenario of 56K guys streaming your vids is a little ridiculous. unless you adapt it to a resolution of 4x4, he's gonna suffer lags anyway ;-) i don't know what the equivalent MicroSoft Server would cost, but i bet it's not free either.

Comment: @back2dos: want to delver a little deeper into why MXML is more powerful than XAML because it contains AS3? Also, Smooth Stream is available to any Windows Server (running IIS) as a free addon.

Answer (score 3):

I always think that if you should compare Silverlight with any Adobe product then Flex is the one.

Answer (score 0):

-5 Both require client side software.  On the client side Flash Player is needed, or the Silver Light runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There is one huge downside to flex in that it hasn't got any native support for ws-security.  Only a problem if you want to consume web services securely.  So securing service calls in flex is just that bit harder.

To top it off no support for SOAP1.2 either! Although that ones not that hard to overcome with a bit of jiggery pokery!

I do like flex though, but as with anything it has its down sides.

Answer (score 0):

About

3) faster for developing ?

Depends on your team, if your team is a .net focused one... SL is the technology to choose you will save ramp up time, if not... then hard time choosing which one is the one that suits better your needs (I cannot tell you honestly because I have a SL heart :P).

Cheers
  Braulio